# html </script> is not placing inside a single quotes

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my program i wanted to append block of html code using js append statement as follows

```html
<script>
    $("#day_s_add{{ $row['hdr_id'] }}").click(function () {
        $("#day_s{{ $row['hdr_id'] }}").append('<script> $(function() { $( "#datepicker{{ $row["hdr_id"] }}" ).datepicker({   dateFormat : "dd-mm-yy",  }); });</script>');
    });
</script>
```

here the `</script>` tag inside single quotes on append statement is not working :( how to make the closing script tag as a normal string.

thanks

Comment: Do not append a script tag, call the code directly....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try escaping the closing tag?
You also missing closing `)};`.

Try:

```
$("#day_s_add{{ $row['hdr_id'] }}").click(function () {
    var str = '<script>$(function() {$( "#datepicker{{ $row["hdr_id"] }}" )' +
    '.datepicker({   dateFormat : "dd-mm-yy",  }); });\</script>';
    $("#day_s{{ $row['hdr_id'] }}").append(str);

});
```

And please respect peoples which will help you, format your sample!

Comment: sorry julien i tried formatting but it still shows like that only

Answer (score 0):

There is ZERO reason to append a script tag when all it is doing is rendering the code and running it. Call the code directly.

```
 $("#day_s_add{{ $row['hdr_id'] }}").click(function () {
    $( "#datepicker{{ $row['hdr_id'] }}" ).datepicker({   dateFormat : "dd-mm-yy",  });
 });
```

Comment: It's true, I don't even think about it when I reed the question (ok, it's appear really weird to do that but I didn't think much...). This should be the accepted answer